# Finding if number is a perfect cube

Tags: python

Hi everyone I just started learning python and am trying to write a function to find if the number entered by the user is a perfect cube or not.

```
def isPerfectCube():
    for i in range(2,int(x/3)):

        if (i**3)==x:
            print('Number is a perfect cube')
        else:
            print ('Not a perfect cube')
print('Enter a number')
x=int(input())
isPerfectCube()
```

but every time I enter a number which isn't a perfect cube it prints:

> Not a perfect cube

until the for loop is complete. I just want it to print once.

Comment: You want to add a [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement after the `print` in the `else` portion of your code. The `break` statement will kick you out of the `for-loop`.

Comment: You actually want to iterate through the possible `i` until either the `if` condition is true or the for-loop is exited (no more possible numbers). Only then you know that `x` isn't a perfect cube.

Comment: Figured it out.
def isPerfectCube():
    for i in range(2,int(x/3)):
      
        if (i**3)==x:
            print('Number is a perfect cube')
            break
    if(i**3)!=x:
      print('Not a cube')
print('Enter a number')
x=int(input())
isPerfectCube()

Answer (score 0):

if you insist on using a for-loop like this, you should use a boolean as a flag and then print the output like this:

```
def isPerfectCube():
    isCube = false
    for i in range(2,int(x/3)):

        if (i**3)==x:
            isCube = true
    if isCube:
            print('Number is a perfect cube')
    else:
            print ('Not a perfect cube')
print('Enter a number')
x=int(input())
isPerfectCube()
```

because you are running through all numbers until the numbers/3 and testing whether or not it matches or not. it's a lot of numbers and for each test, you are printing! but you need to print once!

---

a simpler and faster solution would be this (without a for-loop):

```
print('Enter a number')
x=int(input())
a = x**(1/3)
a = int(round(a))
if a**3 == z:
    print('Number is a perfect cube')
else:
    print ('Not a perfect cube')
```

because you don't need to test all numbers between 1 to `x/3`, you only need to test if `x/3` power by 3, is x or not!

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your input, i tried this instead and this seems to be working. I wanted to try it using functions.

```
def isPerfectCube():
    for i in range(2,int(x/3)):

        if (i**3)==x:
            print('Number is a perfect cube')
            break
    if(i**3)!=x:
      print('Not a cube')
print('Enter a number')
x=int(input())
isPerfectCube()
```

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer, your for-loop is really not necessary!!